# How to detect increment or decrement button in a Flex Spinner?

Tags: apache-flex, spinner

How to detect if a increment or decrement button was clicked in a Flex Spinner component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When numericStepper creation completed, get buttons and listen events:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function numericstepper1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var stepper:NumericStepper = NumericStepper(event.target);

                stepper.incrementButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onIncrementClickHandler, false, 0, true);
                stepper.decrementButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onDecrementClickHandler, false, 0, true);
            }

            protected function onIncrementClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("incrementButton click");    
            }

            protected function onDecrementClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("decrementButton click");        
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:NumericStepper creationComplete="numericstepper1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" />

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for the [change](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Spinner.html#event%3achange) event to tell when the item changes.  Of course, clicks on the increment or decrement button are not the only way to tell when the value has changed.

The incrementButton and decrementButton are both [skin parts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Spinner.html#SkinPartSummary).  Since skin parts are public, you could add event listeners for the Button [click](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3aclick) event.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function spinnerClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Alert.show(event.target.id);
    // will show 'incrementButton' or 'decrementButton' 
}

<s:Spinner click="spinnerClick(event)"/>
```